# how to understand typescript Record<string, any> and Record<string, unknown>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type T2 = {
  home: '123456'
  phone: '13111111111'
} extends Record<number, any> ? true : false // true

type T3 = ['sing', 'dance'] extends Record<string, any> ? true : false // true

type T4 = ['sing', 'dance'] extends Record<string, unknown> ? true: false // false

type T5 = ['sing', 'dance'] extends Record<number, unknown> ? true: false // true
```

`T3`, `T4`, `T5`. These three variable are hard to understand. Why? Can anyone answer that?

I think `['sing', 'dance']` stands for `{0: 'sing', 1: 'dance'}`, which explains the formation of `T3`.

But I don't known `T4` and `T5`.

Comment: t5 is true because, like you said, it uses *numeric* keys (the indices).

Comment: Interfaces don't get [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) unless the value type for the index signature is `any` (i.e., `Record<string, any>` is an intended exception to the rule).  So `t3` succeeds because of `Record<string, any>`, `t4` fails because tuples are treated like array interfaces and don't get implicit index signatures, and `t5` succeeds because the array interface has an explicit `number` index signature.

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yep, I known that `Record<string, unknown>` only accept object liked value(i.e. `{}` or `{a: 1}`